# How we maintain To Do in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have been using Lotus Notes from last 1 year.
Now I switched to new company where I have to use Outlook.

Can anybody tell me how to maintain To Do in Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

Outlook has a section called "Tasks" where you can create To Do items, set priorities, due dates, etc.